# Back navigation from PreferenceFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I handle my back navigation like such:

When creating / committing a `Fragment`:

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .addToBackStack("ToDoFragment")
            .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragmentR, fragmentR.getClass().getSimpleName())
            .commit();
```

When catching a back button press:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    // If navigation drawer is open, close it
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
        setDrawerState(true);
        displayMenu(true);
    }
}
```

This works fine for my `Fragments`, but I wish to do the same for my `PreferenceFragment`, that I call like such:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add("ToDoFragment")
                .replace(R.id.content_frame, new SettingsFragment()).commit();
```

But when pressing my back nav. button it does not bring me back to the previous `Fragment`, instead it overlaps my `Settings` view and my previous `Fragment`.

What am I missing / not understanding?

EDIT:

I have added `getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();` to my `onBackPressed()` method, I do not have any view overlapping, but when going into my settings and pressing back, the Fragment is empty.

Answer (score 2):

Using a [PreferenceFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html) you can´t override `onBackPressed()` in this case use `onDetach()` :

```
@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();

    //Do your process here!

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using 'add' in manager use 'addtoBackStack' Because add retains the existing fragments and adds a new fragment which means existing fragment will be active. Hence back button is not called for existing fragment.

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .addToBackStack("ToDoFragment")
 .replace(R.id.content_frame, new SettingsFragment()).commit();
```